# Implementing Generic Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

Trying to implement this:

Interface:

```
public interface IStoreReader
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get<T>(UserDb user);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ConversationDb>> Get<ConversationDb>(UserDb user)
{
    return await _convoRepo.Get(user.UserId); // error here
}
```

Convo repo:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ConversationDb>> Get(string userId)
{
      return await // get from db - this works fine
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste error images

Comment: It looks to me like you have two classes called `ConversationDb` coming from two different namespaces.

Comment: `ConversationDb` in your method is a generic type because you cannot tell it what the actual type is since it's defined on the method.  You likely meant to have `IStoreReader<T>` and just `Get(UserDb user)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the generic type on the method then when you implement it the name you give is just going to be a generic type.  Thus it's saying that the concrete class from your repo is not the same as the generic one that just happens to have the same name.  I believe you actually want to define the generic type on your interface instead.

```
public interface IStoreReader<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get(UserDb user);
}

public class ConversationReader : IStorReader<ConversationDb>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ConversationDb>> Get(UserDb user)
    {
        return await _convoRepo.Get(user.UserId); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two classes called `ConversationDb` in two different namespaces.

The type being returned by the repo is not the same type as the one defined in your implementation. Look at the definition of the types and you will see they come from different places.

The error message is very clear. You are asking the compiler to cast:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SomeNamespace.ConversationDb>
```

to

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConversationDb>
```

You must have imported the namespace for the second case but the repo is returning the first case.

Comment: nope. i made sure. there's only one

Comment: @BobSwanson: I sincerely doubt that and without the obscured part, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: One is a generic type name defined on the `Get` method.